# Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback in matlab

Tags: matlab, slider

I am displaying a slider in MATLAB but it is giving an error that

```
@(hObject,eventdata)rotate('slider1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback.
```

Here is code:

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider

a=get(handles.slider1,'Min',1,'Max',10,'Value',1);

%// error line:

function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

Comment: That's great! What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
a=get(handles.slider1,'Min',1,'Max',10,'Value',1);
```

You can either do:

```
a_min=get(handles.slider1,'Min');
a_max=get(handles.slider1,'Max');
a_val=get(handles.slider1,'Value');
```

if you want to **get** the properties of the `uicontrol`, or:

```
a=set(handles.slider1,'Min',1,'Max',10,'Value',1);
```

if you want to **set** the properties of the `uicontrol`.

**EDIT following comments**:

It sounds as if you want to display the current value of the slider in an edit text box. Then you need to do:

```
a_val=get(handles.slider1,'Value');
str=sprintf('Slider value %f',a_val); 
set(handles.text1,'String',str);
```

Make sure your questions are well posed and self-contained, we can't guess what it is you are trying to do unless you actually tell us.

Comment: I want to show value of slider in edit text 
a=set(handles.slider1,'Min',1,'Max',10,'Value',1);
a_min=get(handles.slider1,'Min');
a_max=get(handles.slider1,'Max');
a_val=get(handles.slider1,'Value');
str=sprintf('Slider value %f',a);
set(handles.text1,'String',str);
but it is not displaying its value in static text.

Comment: What is it displaying then? It's difficult to help you without seeing the code. Check that `a_val` is actually what you expect (e.g. with `disp(a_val)` after getting the slider value, check that you have the correct handles in `handles.slider1`, `handles.text1`, etc... I can't use my crystal ball to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Also, why do you have that line in your callback function? `function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)` It doesn't make sense to have it twice, you only need it once to define the function

Comment: Other suggestion: it might be worth trying a static text rather than an editable text, as the idea behind the editable text is to **get**, rather than **set**, the string that the use manually entered in the text box. If you're only going to update the string based on the value of the slider, a static text would be a better choice.